# Repetitive jQuery click functions for changing multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the following code to change elements text and classes when a `click` event is fired. My question is: Is there a better way to go about doing this that limits how repetitive the functions are? It seems extremely messy and like there would be a better way to go about structuring this.

```
function updateAveragesDropdown(element, text) {
    // Update text
    $("#timeframe_dropdown_container .dropdown-toggle p").text(text);

    // Remove active class
    $("#timeframe_dropdown_container #dropdown_today").parent("li").removeClass("active");
    $("#timeframe_dropdown_container #dropdown_week").parent("li").removeClass("active");
    $("#timeframe_dropdown_container #dropdown_month").parent("li").removeClass("active");

    // Update nav-tabs
    $("#timeframe_pills_container #tab_today").parent("li").removeClass("active");
    $("#timeframe_pills_container #tab_week").parent("li").removeClass("active");
    $("#timeframe_pills_container #tab_month").parent("li").removeClass("active");

    // Add active class
    $(element).parent("li").addClass("active");
}

function removeDropdownClasses() {
    $("#timeframe_dropdown_container #dropdown_today").parent("li").removeClass("active");
    $("#timeframe_dropdown_container #dropdown_week").parent("li").removeClass("active");
    $("#timeframe_dropdown_container #dropdown_month").parent("li").removeClass("active");
}

function updateDropdownElement(element, text) {
     $(element).parent("li").addClass("active");
     $("#timeframe_dropdown_container .dropdown-toggle p").text(text);
}

// Clear active labels on dropdown menu
$("#timeframe_dropdown_container #dropdown_today").click(function(e) {
    updateAveragesDropdown(this, "Today");
    $("#timeframe_pills_container #tab_today").parent("li").addClass("active");
});

$("#timeframe_dropdown_container #dropdown_week").click(function(e) {
    updateAveragesDropdown(this, "7-Day");
    $("#timeframe_pills_container #tab_week").parent("li").addClass("active");
});

$("#timeframe_dropdown_container #dropdown_month").click(function(e) {
    updateAveragesDropdown(this, "30-Day");
    $("#timeframe_pills_container #tab_month").parent("li").addClass("active");
});

$("#timeframe_pills_container #tab_today").click(function(e) {
    removeDropdownClasses();
    updateDropdownElement("#timeframe_dropdown_container #dropdown_today", "Today");
});

$("#timeframe_pills_container #tab_week").click(function(e) {
    removeDropdownClasses();
    updateDropdownElement("#timeframe_dropdown_container #dropdown_week", "7-Day");
});

$("#timeframe_pills_container #tab_month").click(function(e) {
    removeDropdownClasses();
    updateDropdownElement("#timeframe_dropdown_container #dropdown_month", "30-Day");
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="timeframe_pills_container">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#today_tab" id="tab_today">Today</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#week_tab" id="tab_week">7-Day</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#month_tab" id="tab_month">30-Day</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="dropdown" id="timeframe_dropdown_container">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="timeframe_dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            <p>Today</p>
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="timeframe_dropdown">
            <li class="active" data-toggle="tab" href="#today_tab"><a id="dropdown_today">Today</a></li>
            <li data-toggle="tab" href="#week_tab" ><a id="dropdown_week">7-Day</a></li>
            <li data-toggle="tab" href="#month_tab" ><a id="dropdown_month">30-Day</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show your HTML structure.  My guess is that a lot of your repetitive code might be related to how you have your elements structured in DOM.  You may need both changes to HTML and javascript to improve your solution.

Comment: @MikeBrant See updated post please.

Comment: Are you using any JQuery plugins? I ask because the output HTML is reminiscent of a control that is rendering the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the code simplifies as follows :

```
$("#timeframe_pills_container li a").click(function(e) {
  var $li = $(this).closest("li");
  var index = $li.index();
  var $dropdown = $("#timeframe_dropdown_container");
  $li.addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
  $dropdown.find("li").eq(index).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
  $dropdown.find(".dropdown-toggle p").text($(this).text());
}).eq(0).click();

$("#timeframe_dropdown_container li a").click(function(e) {
  var index = $(this).closest("li").index();
  $("#timeframe_pills_container li a").eq(index).click();
});
```

`.eq(0).click()` establishes the intial state, so you don't need to set `class="active"` (twice) or the button text, in HTML.